# Understanding proof of martingale transform being supermartingale

Tags: probability, expectation, martingales, conditional-expectation

I am reading "Probability with Martingales" by David Williams. On page 97 the following theorem and proof is stated:

> **Theorem**: *Let $C$ be a bounded non-negative previsible process so that, for some $K\in[0,\infty)$, $|C_n(\omega)|\le K$ for every $n$ and every $\omega$. Let $X$ be a supermartingale [respectively martingale]. Then $C\bullet X$ is a supermartingale [martingale] null at $0$.*
>
> **Proof**: Write $Y$ for $C\bullet X$. Since $C_n$ is bounded non-negative and $F_{n-1}$-measurable,
> $E[Y_n-Y_{n-1}|F_{n-1}]=C_nE[X_n-X_{n-1}|F_{n-1}]\le0$, [resp. $=0$].

In the above $C\bullet X$ (and $Y_n$) is defined as $(C\bullet X)_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n} C_k(X_k-X_{k-1})=Y_n$
and in particular $(C\bullet X)_0=0$ and $Y_n-Y_{n-1}=C_n(X_n-X_{n-1})$.

Now, in the proof, I understand how the author gets the first equality, but how is the last inequality [equality for martingale] established and why does this conclude the theorem? I.e., how is it that (for the case of supermartingale) $C_nE[X_n-X_{n-1}|F_{n-1}]\le0$, and how does this conclude that $C\bullet X$ is supermartingale?

I get that $X_{n-1}$ is $F_{n-1}$-measurable, so  $E[X_{n-1}|F_{n-1}]=E[X_{n-1}]$, but is $X_n$ somehow also $F_{n-1}$-measurable, and if this is the case how do we clarify this?

And, as previously mentioned, how does $E[Y_n-Y_{n-1}|F_{n-1}]=C_nE[X_n-X_{n-1}|F_{n-1}]\le0$ in itself conclude that $E[Y_n | F_{n-1}]\le Y_{n-1}$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Where possible, it's far better to actually type definitions in rather than link to PDFs. It's easier for the reader to understand what you're asking, and it's better for searching.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that $\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1} \mid F_{n-1}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}]$, but that is not right. Since $X_{n-1}$ is $F_{n-1}$-measurable, in fact $\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1} \mid F_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}$. Since $X$ is a supermartingale, we also have $\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid F_{n-1}] \leq X_{n-1}$. So, using linearity of conditional expectation, we have
$$\mathbb{E}[X_n-X_{n-1}\mid F_{n-1}] = \mathbb{E}[X_n\mid F_{n-1}]-\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1} \mid F_{n-1}] \leq X_{n-1}-X_{n-1} = 0.$$
Since $C_n$ is nonnegative, the same inequality holds if we put $C_n$ out front.

Now we have established that $\mathbb{E}[Y_n-Y_{n-1}\mid F_{n-1}] \leq 0$, and you ask why does that imply $Y$ is a supermartingale? It should be clear that $Y_n$ is $F_n$-measurable and integrable, so all that remains is to show $\mathbb{E}[Y_n \mid F_{n-1}] \leq Y_{n-1}$. Similarly to what we did above, this follows from linearity of conditional expectation and the fact that $\mathbb{E}[Y_{n-1}\mid F_{n-1}] = Y_{n-1}$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y_n \mid F_{n-1}] &= \mathbb{E}[(Y_n-Y_{n-1})+Y_{n-1} \mid F_{n-1}]\\
& = \mathbb{E}[Y_n-Y_{n-1} \mid F_{n-1}]+\mathbb{E}[Y_{n-1}\mid F_{n-1}]\\
&\leq 0 + Y_{n-1}\\
&=Y_{n-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I guess that you mean that $E[X_{n-1} | F_{n-1}]=X_{n-1}$, right? My mistake was that I foolishly used the property for conditional expectation when $\sigma(X_{n-1})$ and $F_{n-1}$ is independent, instead of the property when $X_{n-1}$ is $F_{n-1}$-measurable. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant - I copied the equation and forgot to remove the $\mathbb{E}$.